# Connection issue when using hbase in ambari

Tags: hadoop, hbase, ambari

Recently I have been working on Ambari. But after I installed successfully, everything is working well except the HBase. Only the HBase master is good, and other RegionServers all get the alert:

> Connection failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused to server1.hadoop:16030. (the domain name differs from machines.)

Anyone have the same problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue. I read the log file in /var/log/hbase/*.log of my region servers ,and find that it's clock is not sync with the master's. So I make all the servers to sync its clock to the master's using ntpd. Then I restart the ambari components and no alert showed up!!!
Think this may help those with the problem.

Comment: I added a machine and this error shows up again. Since it only occurs on the single machine, I deleted it... ... Now it looks pretty good in the admin page with no alerts, hope it may not be followed with problems.

Comment: That happened again!!!! and again i go to the log file and find that my name node is in safe mode. I don't know how it came up, and then I use the command to close safe mode.
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave